# bash - How to only keep specific characters from a string

Tags: string, bash, shell

In my script I need to only keep specific characters from a string.
For example:

```
string="aPRO100z"
```

How do I get to the following result?

```
result="PRO100"
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: How are you deciding which characters to keep? Do you want to keep all but the first & last chars, as in Amit's answer? Or do want to drop lower case letters like `a` and `z`? Or what???

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sed` command:

```
# in this example, we keep only the chars 0-9 and A-Z
result=`echo $string | sed 's/[^0-9A-Z]*//g'`;
```

Comment: It seems that this removes the characters instead of keeping them. Another answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511639/sed-print-only-matching-group

Answer (score -2):

Using `cut`:

```
result=$(echo ${string} | cut -c 2-7)
```

Comment: the OP asked to _keep only specific charactes_ and not _keep characters from position 2 to 7_

Comment: @Jav  What do you mean by that? The output of my answer is same as yours. Please let OP respond instead of you assuming anything and down voting other's answers.

Comment: Well, you keep specific positions, and I keep specific characters. The OP wanted to keep specific characters so the answer you give doesn't seem to meet the requirements (I assumed, indeed, that the OP knows what he wants ... which might not be the case.).